# GWT - Module.gwt.xml - XML validation warning

Tags: xml, validation, gwt, doctype

If I create a new GWT 2.6 project in the latest eclipse version (kepler), I always get the following warning message:

```
The file cannot be validated as the XML definition "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/
 2.6.0/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd" that is specified as describing the syntax of the file
```

in my Module.gwt.xml next to the line:

```
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.6.0//EN"
"http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.6.0/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
```

Should this file ("http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.6.0/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dt") be available if I call it in the browser?

Or what does this error tell me? how can i resolve this warning?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

There's already a bug report [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=8599).

For now, you can still use the one from 2.5.1

```
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.5.1//EN" "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.5.1/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
```

---

**UPDATE**:

The new DTDs are now available here:

```
http://www.gwtproject.org/doctype/<version-number>/gwt-module.dtd
```

So for example:

```
http://www.gwtproject.org/doctype/2.8.0/gwt-module.dtd
```

Comment: Even your updated DTD URL doesn't work for me.

This forum post (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/NYyfq4tF880) makes me think that online hosting of it is going away.

Comment: @Bdoserror Well, the links I posted have been created after that post. And they are on the official homepage, which makes me think they are going to be maintained. Links still work for me btw.

Comment: I ended up just creating a new GWT project in Eclipse and then copying that doc spec, which worked. It ended up being like your first answer, except with 2.6.0 as the version. Weird.

Comment: @QuinnTurner Actually, with 2.8.0 released now, there's a new file you could use now. I've updated my answer.

Comment: The `www.` at the front is important. *sigh*

Comment: Is there a new doctype dtd for gwt 2.9.0? I am getting an Error: Not Found when I go to http://www.gwtproject.org/doctype/2.9.0/gwt-module.dtd

Comment: @bdrx Sorry, no idea. I've left GWT behind me and I'm really happy I moved away from it.