# The markup declarations contained or pointed to by the document type declaration must be well-formed

Tags: java, xml, libgdx

So I'm using a library called libgdx for a java project. It has an autogenerated XML file which I have no idea what does. Suddenly this xml file returns an error which is:

> "The markup declarations contained or pointed to by the document type declaration must be well-formed"

Having no idea what the xml file does or any deep knowledge of xml I'm completely stuck as to how to fix it. The XML code can be seen here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit trunk//EN" "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module>
    <source path="com/starship/security" />
</module>
```

Comment: The error message states that the DTD found at http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd is not valid. Did you have a look at it?

Comment: No I haven't, I'm afraid I have no knowledge of DTDs :(

Answer (score 1):

**The problem**

The URL `http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd` does not point to a DTD file. I do not know whether it did before, but now you can see a redirection hint when simply calling this URL in your browser.

The redirection points you to the URL `https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt/+/master/./distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd`. However, under this URL you get a simple HTML page that displays the DTD. *You do not get the DTD file itself.*

So the error message is correct. The HTML page is not a valid DTD.

**A solution**

You must reference a valid DTD. Point.

A first simple approach - with which you also can check the behavior - would be to save this DTD to your local hard disk and reference it with

```
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit trunk//EN" "file:///<absolute-path>/gwt-module.DTD">
```

In fact, I do not know whether this DTD is part of your project or whether it is maybe accessible in a more public place in the web. In the first case you can replace the absolute path with a project relative path. In the second case you must replace the whole URL.

Maybe you can troubleshoot on that last step yourself. I am (unfortunately) not familiar with GWT.

Comment: Yes, I saw that, however we are working on thi project on three computers, and only I am getting the error and only as of recently, so I doubt it's the redirect problem, but thank you for the input nevertheless, I'll look into it ^^

Comment: @SanderSkovgaardHansen I get the problem on my computer, too. **So it is the redirect problem.**

Comment: Reading your explanation again I can see I misunderstood some stuff about the redirection, thank you very much, I will try out the stuff you pointed out ^^

Comment: @SanderSkovgaardHansen No, I do not mind. My "answer" is in fact not a complete answer. But it was too large to put into a comment. I simply wanted to show you the direction for further research. Glad to hear that you found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's a bug in the 2.6 version og their DTD. What did the trick was replacing the second line with:

```
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.5.1//EN" "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.5.1/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
```

Source:
[GWT - Module.gwt.xml - XML validation warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22865648/gwt-module-gwt-xml-xml-validation-warning)