# Update gwt-module.dtd

Tags: xml, inheritance, gwt, dtd

i use java compiler 1.8
i use installed JREs jdk-17
when compiling maven packages from batch file or in Eclipse with call mvn clean install

i get this error

```
[INFO] Compiling module mleWidgeset.MLEWidgetset
[INFO]    [ERROR] Hint: Check that your module inherits 'com.google.gwt.core.Core' either directly or indirectly (most often by inheriting module 'com.google.gwt.user.User')
```

so I do a bit of scouting on this platform like

[GWT - Module.gwt.xml - XML validation warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22865648/gwt-module-gwt-xml-xml-validation-warning)
[GWT Error: There is '1' error in 'gwt-module.dtd'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67316333/gwt-error-there-is-1-error-in-gwt-module-dtd)

I find that the .xml files need to be updated to update the gwt DTD modules so i update these references

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 
2.5.1//EN" "http://google-web- 
toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.5.1/distro-source/core/src/gwt- 
module.dtd">
```

with these

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 
2.9.0//EN" "http://www.gwtproject.org/doctype/2.9.0/gwt-module.dtd">
```

but i get this error in all projects where updated .xml files like above

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRN8V.png)

Can you help me understand how to fix it? the gwt dtd file link is correct, putting it in chrome browser downloads the DTD file

Answer (score 1):

GWT doesn't require the "?xml" and "!DOCTYPE" lines, so you can just remove them. Also, "user.User" inherits "core.Core", so you can remove the last one.

Anyway, the error doesn´t seem related to the DTD. If you have updated GWT version, you may have mixed version in the classpath. And if you have updated the JDK version, then maybe you need to use the last GWT release.

Maybe it is better to use [gitter#gwt](https://app.gitter.im/#/room/#gwtproject_gwt:gitter.im) to solve your doubt.

Comment: hi Ignacio Bacà

Comment: thanks for the reply, i'm a bit confused... because in the previous version of my widgetset .xml files i had no problems and there were already the lines that i attached with DTD to version 2.5.1, they are part of a complete webapp distributed, then I updated all Eclipse Neon IDE plugins to version 2023 (as suggested by Eclipse) updated java JDK 1.8 to JDK version 17, including pointing environment variables.

Comment: previous version <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.5.1//EN" "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.5.1/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module>
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.User"/>
    <inherits name="com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet"/>
...
    <inherits name="org.vaadin.jouni.dom.DomWidgetset" />    
    <inherits name="org.vaadin.addons.WidgetSet" />       
    <inherits name="mleWidgeset.MLEWidgetset" />
...
</module>

Comment: Then came the error Hint: module inherits 'com.google.gwt.core.Core'... suggesting to update version of gwt DTDs in .xml widgetsets, but definitively the error has moved as indicated above, these last .xml files include many inherited vaadin modules and the indicated initial lines are present from the beginning... so finally error remain is in the attached image. I removed core.Core as you indicated because its redundant, but I don't understand why the error indicated in the attached image does not appear if I use gwt dtd v2.5.1 (old link) but occur if I insert the link to new one 2.9.0 dtd

Comment: Download the DTD file and open it in eclipse, maybe it'll show the exact problem.